# How do I poll a child branch on Git using Poll SCM on Jenkins? I can't use webhook due to restrictions

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

Create a jenkins pipeline with Pipeline as SCM enabled.
Set default branch as child branch.
Include branch as parameter to job.
Use checkout plugin

Even though last built revision (in Jenkins build log) is from “develop” branch, Jenkins Git Polling log shows last built revision to be from main

Checking out Revision ac535d3fd2aa54e9101680dea3e9bfa9089bce7f (refs/remotes/origin/develop)

[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision aa5b903e1f63f2fe029b82404e9b2d5988145d79 (origin/main)

I expected Jenkins to poll the child branhc

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.